# The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/project/frontend/web/assets Yii2

Tags: linux, yii2

chmod 777 assets не помогает. Права доступа остаются старые
[image: Скрин PuTTY]

Спасибо)))

Comment: Надо же web/assets, судя по ошибке. Обычно эти разрешения выставляются при выполнении инициализации приложения.

Comment: Спасибо) так же не меняются права и у web/assets(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если центос, то настройте selinux. Если ubuntu - apparmor. Или отключите их до лучших времен.

Попробуйте `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/` - это правильней.

Посмотрите `/var/log/auth.log` на сообщения от selinux\apparmor.

Странно что chmod не сработал. Может опечатка?

Мало данных: будет больше - дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, не помогло(( после команды chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ права остаются те же

Comment: права то ладно.. юзер сменился? что в auth.log?